# Complete the gap in a ranked poset (even number of ways?)

Tags: combinatorics, homological-algebra, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let P be a ranked finite poset and suppose $x < z$ where $\textrm{rank}(z) = \textrm{rank}(x)+2$. Define the interval as
$$ I_{xz} = \{y: x < y < z\} $$
Is there a simple criterion for $|I_{xz}|$ to be *even*? Do you have a reference?
A linear order does not satisfy this property. The poset of subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ does (maybe because it is a lattice?).

**Context:** In case the free vector space $\mathbb{F}_2 P$ is *graded*, that is we have a map $\partial: \mathbb{F}_2 P \to \mathbb{F}_2 P$ with $\partial^2 = 0$, one can define its subdivision $s(P)$ as generated (over $\mathbb{F}_2$) in degree $k$ by chains of degree $k$. The differential in $s(P)$ is given by
$$D(p_0 < \ldots < p_k ) = \sum_{i=0}^k p_0 < \ldots < \hat{p}_i < \ldots < p_k$$
that is, excluding one the elements of the chain. The property above (almost) ensures that the map of subdivision
$$ sd(p) = \sum_{C_{\bullet} \in \max_{\le}(p) } C_{\bullet} $$
where $\max_{\le}(p)$ is the set of maximal chains with greatest element $p$, is a map of chain complexes. This is particularly interesting because the subdivision complex does not depend on the differential $\partial$ chosen on the poset.

Comment: It certainly does not have anything to do with the lattice property, since (for example) the finite linear order is a lattice, and every possible interval of height 2 taken by itself is a lattice.

Comment: I am pretty skeptical that this condition by itself can be expressed in any nicer way but it is implied by some nice properties; in particular, every Eulerian poset has this property.